# how to uninstall all python packages

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, uninstallation

I just updated `numpy` and it seems that there is a conflict between `matplotlib` and the newest version of `numpy`. I have `matplotlib 1.1.1rc`. I tried to upgrade `matplotlib` using the following command:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

I got the following warning:

```
The directory '/home/po/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by 
the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and
owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

The package was downloaded and installed, and at the end of the process I received the following:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yq3kB5/matplotlib`

I am thinking to uninstall all the packages and then install them all over again. Is there a quick way to do that?

### Edit 1

I wrote in the terminal:

```
sudo -H pip install -U matplotlib
```

I got the following:

```sh
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-1.5.0.tar.gz (54.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 54.0MB 7.3kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options`

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [1.5.0]
                    python: yes [2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41)  [GCC
                            4.6.3]]
                  platform: yes [linux2]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.10.1]
                  dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.4.2]
                      pytz: yes [using pytz version 2015.7]
                    cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                   tornado: yes [using tornado version 4.2.1]
                 pyparsing: yes [matplotlib requires pyparsing >= 1.5.6]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: yes [version 1.2.46]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                            found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: yes [using nose version 1.1.2 / mock is required to
                            run the matplotlib test suite. "setup.py test" will
                            automatically download it. Install mock to run
                            matplotlib.test()]
            toolkits_tests: yes [using nose version 1.1.2 / mock is required to
                            run the matplotlib test suite. "setup.py test" will
                            automatically download it. Install mock to run
                            matplotlib.test()]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: yes [installing, Qt: 4.8.1, PyQt: 4.8.1; PySide not
                            found]
                   gtk3agg: yes [installing, version 3.2.4]
                 gtk3cairo: yes [installing, version 3.2.4]
                    gtkagg: no  [The C/C++ header for gtk (gtk/gtk.h) could not
                            be found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                     tkagg: no  [The C/C++ header for Tk (tk.h) could not be
                            found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [The C/C++ header for gtk (gtk/gtk.h) could not
                            be found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: yes [installing, pycairo version 1.8.8]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: yes [version 1.14]
               ghostscript: yes [version 9.05]
                     latex: yes [version 3.1415926]
                   pdftops: yes [version 0.18.4]

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-elVWaU/matplotlib
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

But still when I close python, load it all over again, and write:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.__version__
```

I get `1.1.1rc`

Comment: You don't need to do that. First, follow the warning's instructions and use `sudo -H pip install -U matplotlib`. If you're still having problems, please [edit] your question and post the **entire** traceback.

Comment: I tried that, then I wrote `matplotlib.__version__`. The version is still `1.1.1rc1. Check the edit for the details. @MattDMo

Comment: Try installing `freetype-dev` or `libfreetype-dev` using your operating system's package manager, as that seems to be causing the error. The SSL warning is just a warning, but I'd recommend visiting the link and following the instructions there.

Comment: @MattDMo, still it is not working!  Any thoughts?

Comment: As a side note, this is an example of why it's considered bad practice to `sudo pip install` into your system directories. If you had installed locally, such as into a  [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or in your home directory using `pip install --user` then if all else fails you could safely delete the whole directory containing the broken modules and start again.

Comment: Try installing [directly](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html) rather than using `pip` for matplotlib

Comment: @dawg, I tried. Still, it is not working. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked, here's what I did:

First, I uninstalled matplotlib using the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-matplotlib
```

Then, because `pip` does not install system level dependencies, I downloaded `freetype` using the command:

```
apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

And then, I reinstalled `matplotlib` using the command

```
sudo -H pip install matplotlib
```

Note:
I guess `uninstalling` and `reinstalling` matplotlib was meaningless. I could have first installed `freetype` and then upgraded `matplotlib` using:

```
sudo -H pip install -U matplotlib
```

Comment: Still, this does not answer the question you asked, which is: _How to uninstall all python packages_.